# What is causing a ~24MB Index.js file in production Webpacker React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I have a rails 6 application with react that is running webpacker 5.0. The current issue I am having is on the initial load of the web application (on mobile) is occasionally very slow, like 40-120 seconds slow (I have not yet determined why sometimes its slow and sometimes it isn't). When taking a look at the network tab it appears loading the index-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.js file is what eats up most of the load time (see image).

[image]

I am by no means a React build or deployment expert so I am at a bit of a loss on how to resolve this. I did run the visual bundle analyzer plugin and the index-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.js chunk size was ~4mb which is confusing given the findings in the network tab. I was mindful to use named routing for imports with MUI and most all of the imports on the react side, as well as cleaning up dead code and unused libraries; so most of the low hanging fruit has been plucked. Before I embark on Code splitting, tree shaking, or migrating to Shakapacker I would love to get some insight on what I am dealing with. Is that index-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.js actually needed (why are there also tiny index chunks) or is it some unintentional vestige of my build process?

Comment: Does your bundler bundle images into the JavaScript? Does it bundle many large libraries?

Comment: I'd a try a tool like [webpack visualizer](https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/) or another bundle analyzer.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I think it does include images, but they are tiny maybe 500kb, The largest libraries the application uses is Fabric.js and MUI, and I don't think though would be the cause given the size of them, but I welcome being wrong.

Comment: All images together are 500kb or each of the 48 images is 500kb?

Comment: @ThomasSablik total, I optimized them prior to adding them to the project.

Comment: May you share your `webapcker.yml`? In particular, I want to know about your `source_entry_path` and `nested_entries`. I wonder if you are telling webpack to bundle everything in your `source_path`